# How to add an invisible bounding box to an SKSpriteNode for better touchEvent detection?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I currently have a small sprite in the shape of a raindrop that moves quite fast across the screen, and it's pretty hard sometimes for the user to tap it and trigger the touchEvent. I can't make the sprite any bigger, and I must retain the raindrop shape, so I want to make an invisible bounding box centered on the raindrop that will detect touchEvents. This will allow the user some leeway on their touches and not make it so frustrating. What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is using a Graphics Editor to create a bigger transparent image with the original raindrop image at the center.

When SpriteKit load the new image it will automatically create a bigger frame **without** drawbacks by the visual or performance points of views.